# Is it possible to ui:include files from an absolute file path rather than relative webapp path?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, uiinclude

Suppose I have the following in my JSF page:

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
```

If this is changing to be static content loading from a non-webapp path - is is possible to change my `ui:include` to an absolute path on the file system?

Assumptions:

- Mojarra 2.0
- Java 7.0
- Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a mac (for example) the path look like this:

```
<ui:include src="file:///Users/Julian/Documents/.../WEB-INF/templates/footer.xhtml" />
```

On Windows the path looks like this:

```
<ui:include src="file:///C:/Users/.../footer.xhtml" />
```

Comment: So, in Windows 3 slashes before the absolute path, in Mac/Unix only 2?